# C++ - return pointer or const reference

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, return-value

I have a Container that has a vector of objects.

```
class Container
{
    vector<Foo> objects;
```

I want to

- Have read only access to these objects as a caller
- Avoid calling copy constructor
- Ignore the problem of accessing these objects after the container goes out of scope (this will never happen)

Based on that, it seems like I have 2 choices for the getter method. Either return const reference to a vector, or return pointer to const vector

```
const vector<Foo> & getRef() { return objects; }
const vector<Foo> * getPtr() { return &objects; }
```

Of course, if I'm the caller, I need to make sure to not call copy constructor when I iterate. So I'd this

```
for (const Foo & f : getRef())
```

and not

```
for (Foo f : getRef())
```

Now, should I return const reference? or pointer to const? What's the benefits and drawbacks?

Comment: Usually pointers are used when what you return can be null, but in this case it's a vector so it can't really be null.. I would go with the const-ref

Comment: Your 3rd choice, imho always better, is to bring the function (which calls the getter and uses the reference) into the Container - thus no getter needed.  See encapsulation: (from wiki) "A language construct that facilitates the bundling of data with the methods (or other functions) operating on that data."

Answer (score 2):

A reference is more robust.  You can't accidentally call delete on it.